# Getting an error while execution protractor test cases on Iphone/IPad real devices using browserstack

Tags: iphone, ipad, protractor, mobile-safari, browserstack

I am executing protractor e2e test cases for angular application on IPhone & IPad real devices using browserstack. I am able to launch application but that is not doing any action after launch and i am getting below error

- Configure the amount of time that a particular type of operation can
  execute for before they are aborted and a |Timeout| error is returned
  to the client.16000

  - Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

I also tried with below code before launching browser :

```
browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;
```

Below are my capabilities :

```
 {
        //IOS -IPhone 8
'browserstack.user': 'cxapsdpajpsdjpa',
      'browserstack.key': 'adasdadsw3gMtN',
      'browserstack.local': 'true',
      'browserstack.debug': 'true',
        'device': 'iPhone 8',
        'realMobile': 'true',
        'os_version': '11.0',
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        'browserstack.local':'true',
        'browserstack.debug':'true',
        'browserstack.networkLogs':'true'

      },
```

Please refer attached snapshot of visual exception log on browser stack

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of this: [Selenium/Protractor .NET test hangs when using BrowserStack iPhone on remote website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51562359)

Pasting the answer below for reference:

I understand you are running Protractor tests on real iOS devices. Protractor injects JavaScripts using execute_async method. The execute_async method is not fully supported by Appium due to which you may be seeing failures. You will find more details on the issue at the links below:

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2840

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1736

Comment: I tried to use browser.ignoreSynchronization=true; before browser.get('/'); but i got the same issue. Could you please help me more , because my application is angular so making ingoresync=true, will taking too much time to load first page itself

Comment: According to the comments in the thread I shared earlier, that (ignoresync) is the only alternative at least until Protractor fixes it.

Comment: Thanks @Kireeti Annamaraj, So final conclusion is we dont have any solution to run protractor tests on iOS except browser.ignoreSynchronization=true;  , but as my application is angular, i can not ignore this settings and also for me its working on android devices

Comment: Anyone able to execute protractor test cases on Ipad and IPhone , please let me know , i am still getting error like 05:120STOP SESSION
SO_TIMEOUT